# How do you format the date filter selection box for Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2013

I created a PivotTable in Excel 2013 and used a date value as a filter. When I want to filter by a range I have to select the individual days. The option looks like:

- 1/1/2013
- 1/2/2013
- 1/3/2013

When I filter the date in the records table the date selection is much more intuitive:

```
[x]2013
-[ ]January
 -[ ]1
 -[ ]2
 -[ ]3
```

Is there anyway to get this format in the pivot table field date filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. (Is this even an acceptable answer?)

You'll find that some "shared" functionalities between Tables and PivotTables aren't always identical - Custom Filters is another one.

But there's an alternative: you can create a few extra columns in your source records table to deal with that. You just have to fill them with a simple formula based on your date cells. That would be Year:

```
=YEAR(Date)
```

and Month,to your liking:

```
=MONTH(Date)                 ' shows 1 (January)
=TEXT(MONTH(Date), "mmm")    ' shows "Jan"
=TEXT(MONTH(Date), "mmmm")   ' shows "January"
```

You can then use those 2 fields in the "Report Filter" area of your PivotTable as a handy and quick access for filtering your dates.

Another *huge* benefit of adding these fields is that you can also use them for breaking down your PivotTables by year or month without having to mess with pivot groupings.

Comment: Great option, other than writing VBA code which I have minimal experience with. Thanks.