# Making a pivot table month filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm trying to compile some reports through an Excel pivot table connected to a MS SQL database. Now the data I'm working with consists of a bunch of dates formated as dd/mm/yy. I want to make a filter based on the months of these dates but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's kind of convoluted, which is why you might be having trouble. You can read about it in the [KB](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-data-in-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-ca3ae673-95ac-46ab-b31a-7e3c5265c422).

So say you create your table with dates as rows and items as columns and you're taking the sum.

- Click, on the table, the down arrow on "Row Labels" (assuming these are the dates).
- You'll want to ***Filter by label*** (not filter by value) - between - 1/1/15 and 1/31/15 (for January).
- There are also custom options like "this month" and "YTD".

<sub>*click to view larger*</sub>
[image]

*Note - For an OLAP data source, date filters require the OLAP cube field hierarchy data type of time. If a date is entered as text in a text field, then the date filter is not visible.*

Also related (not duplicate): [How do you format the date filter selection box for Excel Pivot Table](https://superuser.com/q/538874/116196)